# C# number -> bytes -> string -> first symbol not equal to initial number

Tags: c#

I have code.
I suppose to have 189 'S' as first char but I have 1029 'S' as first char.
I can't understand reason.

```
long longNumber = 189; 
var longNumberSplittedToBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(longNumber); // as expected 8 bytes array: first is 189
var firstChar = Encoding.Default.GetChars(longNumberSplittedToBytes)[0]; // First Symbol is S but there is char code 1029 not 189!
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: 1029 == U+0405 == "Cyrillic Capital Letter Dze".  Yes, most fonts will make it look exactly like a latin S.  You live in Moscow, Cyrillic text shoudn't be too surprising.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the default encoding is [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). 
The character 189 (hexadecimal 0xBD) is the Cyrillic Capital Letter Dze (`Ѕ`), wich is [unicode +0405](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0405/index.htm).

C# uses unicode in it's strings and chars. Hexadecimal 0x0405 is 1029 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You are first converting a `long` into a series of bytes. The first one has hex value BD.

Then you are treating that byte array as an encoded string, using *your* default encoding, which apparently is Code Page 1251 Windows Cyrillic, like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195053.aspx

At the hex value "BD" on that codepage you get the `Ѕ`, the "Cyrillic Capital Letter Dze". And this converted to a regular .Net character (which uses unicode) has code 1029.